# Has scala ability to use default parameter with duck typing?

Tags: scala, duck-typing

Has scala ability to use default parameter with duck typing?

Code below throw error: only declarations allowed here

`def test(x: { def x(a:Int, b:Int = 5):Int} ) = x(1)`

Comment: a) I'm confused. b) This isn't duck typing, is it?

Comment: It is duck typing. Test function require any object which has appropriate 'x' method

Comment: I'm not a Scala expert, but I think you'll need to use traits for this. I don't think you can do what you're trying to do with that syntax.

Comment: OK. I'm apparently wrong. Learn something new every day.

Comment: I use a play framework, and i want to pass my view to method. Play framework compile views from html files, and i don't change result object to use a trait

Comment: @MillieSmith - I don't know if duck typing has an accepted formal  definition but this is usually called structural typing, not duck typing. Duck typing implies late binding while this checks statically on the input type (although the implementation may use reflection to do the invocation).

Comment: @MillieSmith I really like to call it static duck typing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is pretty cheesy:

```
scala> def test(x: { def x(a:Int, b:Int):Int ; def x$default$2: Int } ) = x.x(1, x.x$default$2)
warning: there were 2 feature warning(s); re-run with -feature for details
test: (x: AnyRef{def x(a: Int,b: Int): Int; def x$default$2: Int})Int

scala> val y = new { def x(a: Int, b: Int = 5): Int = a + b }
y: AnyRef{def x(a: Int,b: Int): Int; def x$default$2: Int @scala.annotation.unchecked.uncheckedVariance} = $anon$1@232864a3

scala> test(y)
res0: Int = 6
```

A macro could verify that the default is a certain constant expression, presumably.

Answer (score 0):

no... you can't use a default parameter.  Also your x(1) should be x.x(1), since the x you're trying to call is a method `x` on the parameter also called `x`.

You might want to instead do something like:

```
def test(x: { def foo(a:Int,b:Option[Int]):Int }) = x.foo(1, b.getOrElse(5))
```

Or specify a trait defining the method with default args, and mix it into values you want to pass to this method.

Comment: I use a play framework, and i want to pass my view to method. Play framework compile views from html files, and i don't change result object to use a trait